# hiding files with php

Tags: php, node.js, .htaccess

I can't wrap my head around this, and it is SO frustrating. I have no idea how I'd be solving my problem.

I use sockets to connect with my NodeJS server, and I use PHP for routing people to the correct pages. When I route someone to the admin page I check if he is allowed to continue, if so I'll redirect him, if not I won't. Now here's the issue, people can just go to mywebsite.com/browser/admin.html and read everything that's in the admin panel (just the layout and stuff). I don't want people to be able and visit my admin panel to see what admins can do and can't do.

Can I do this in any way? E.g. only show the admin panel if they have a certain rank; if they don't have that rank they **WILL NEVER** be able to visit the admin panel. I'd like to hide the html files and other files somehow.

**Routing - .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
```

RewriteRule ^/browser/admin.html$ index.php?page=admin [L,NC,QSA]

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Routing - index.php**

```
function route(){
    global $db;
    global $user;

    $page = $_GET['page'];

    if(!isset($page)) {
        header('Location: /home');
    }

    if($page === 'home'){
        loadWebpage('index.html', array());
    }else if($page === 'admin'){
        if($user['rank'] !== 'admin'){ /* This works but people can still access the files since they are loaded on the frontend with myexample.com/browser/admin.html */
            echo 'Access denied.';
            return;
        }

        loadWebpage('admin.html', array())
    }
}

route();
```

I'm sorry if I haven't explained it well, but I hope you understand what I mean; I find it difficult to explain the things I want. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Add an auth check in `admin.html`? maybe use `admin.php` instead.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it's taken from the database, when the user is authenticated he gets put into a global variable as object. It actually doesn't serve admin.html, that works. but people can go to the admin panel using its route e.g. /browser/admin.html which is a problem.

Comment: @Mehdi is there also a way to hide the javascript code etc. If I were to use admin.php instead, would I need another check in the admin.php file for if the user is admin?

Comment: Then make a protected route for `/browser/admin.html`.. tbh it sounds all round bad design, why are you using php and not just sticking with node, it seems like your php code is just serving static content anyway which node can do, then you wont need to use apache/rewrites etc..?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm kinda new, so I just used what I knew stuff about. I use sockets to connect with the Node server, when I start a new project I will switch over to Node completely, but I just want to get this done at this point. How do I make a protected route? place the files outside the folder?

Comment: Add another route (if statement) which checks for rank admin then serves the `/browser/admin.html` file.. then add above the `RewriteCond` .. `RewriteRule ^/browser/admin.html$ index.php?page=admin_layout [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone there would be no other way for users to get into the panel then?

Comment: No, as long as they are not logged in as admin. Make sure you place it above RewriteCond or it will load it as normal.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I've updated the .htaccess in the thread post, but it still just lets me redirect to the html file (and the url doesn't update nor rewrite)

Comment: Check your browser cache. Also `?page=admin`'s going to hit that other route.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it wouldn't be a problem if it hit the other route right? as it would then check if the user is an admin etc. I don't see any reason to make a new route for it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there are plenty of ways to go about what you're trying to achieve, but I'll just explain one way of "access-protecting" a certain file.

Create a file in your directory, admin.php. Here, just have some basic code like this:

```
<?php
$accessKey = $_POST['accessKey'];
if ($accessKey == "MyVeryAwesomeAccessKeyThatNobodyKnows") //Change this to whatever you want
{
?>
    <b>This info will only be shown if you're an admin!</b>
<?php
}
else
    echo("Invalid access key.<br>");
?>
```

This code basically checks if the correct access key was sent in, and only if it was, will it load your protected file.

And then, wherever you have to access the admin page, you can put a form or something there like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="admin.php">
    <input name="accessKey" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Load Admin Site" />
</form>
```

The user has to enter in the administrator access key to be granted permission into the protected information page. This way is a bit hackish, but it gets the job done!

Comment: I don't think it's a good sport to just change the name of the file to some random characters? That couldn't be right, could it?

Comment: I agree with you, and I realized that there's a way to do that which avoids that issue! Instead of using the include() function to embed the file you could have the protected file contents between ?> and <?php (in the if statement) to display them directly, ensuring a greater level of security.

Comment: You are suggesting I change my html file into a php file?

Comment: I meant to say, create a new file, admin.php, with the code I provided, and put the contents of your admin.html file on line 6 (<b>This info will only be shown if you're an admin!</b>). Because of the way PHP works, it will only display that HTML code if the if statement is fulfilled and the code path enters the {}.

Comment: I'll try it, minute.

Comment: adding /browser/admin.php to the browser url still results in the site being displayed